# Sum of 3 independent gamma distributed random variable

Tags: probability-distributions

If $X\sim \Gamma(a_1,b)$, $Y\sim\Gamma(a_2,b)$ and $Z\sim\Gamma(a_3,b)$, how to prove that $X+Y+Z \sim \Gamma(a_1+a_2+a_3,b)$ if $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent.

Comment: Of course it suffices to show that $X+Y\sim \Gamma(a_1+a_2,b)$. What are your own thoughts?

Comment: so far 3 methods: prove from joint density function, use moment generating function, and prove using characteristic function. Prove using characteristic function seem to be the easiest way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X\sim\Gamma(a_1,b)$, then its characteristic function is given by $\varphi_X(t)=(1-\frac{it}{b})^{-a_1}$.

By independence of $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, the characteristic function of $X+Y+Z$ is the product of the characteristic functions, i.e. for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$,

$\varphi_{X+Y+Z}(t)=(1-\frac{it}{b})^{-(a_1+a_2+a_3)}$,

and since the characteristic function characterizes the distribution, $X+Y+Z\sim\Gamma(a_1+a_2+a_3,b)$.